# btrfs: What is a "file extent hole"?

Tags: btrfs

When running `btrfs check` I get:

```
Found file extent holes:                       
        start: 3248128, len: 28672
```

- What is a file extent hole?
- What causes them?
- Is there any way to minimise the likelihood of their creation?

  - I am using a portable USB HDD. Besides `umount` before disconnection should I be doing anything else?

Comment: The extent hole-stuff is quite experimental (i think it's not already in). There is a bug in btrfs check that was showíng holes although there weren't some. This got fixed in v4.11.1 (june 2017).

Comment: I am running: `btrfs-progs v4.11.1`. I created this filesystem just today. How can I disable it? (It seems too experimental for my liking!)

Comment: I think `umount` is supposed to flush all writes but I issue a `udisksctl power-off ...` after that from a script I run that backs things up to USB and then I wait until drive's LED stop flickering and changes to a sleeping pulse before I pull the cable out.